# Extending Mojo::Promise

Tags: perl, promise

First time poster, be gentle.

I wanted something similar to Mojo::Promise->all, except with an option to discard certain rejected (or, I guess, resolved) promises dependent on rejection value, as determined by caller.

Only using this internally, so nevermind my polluting the Mojo::Promise:: namespace.

```
package Mojo::Promise::Filter;
use Moose;

extends 'Mojo::Promise';

has 'promises' => (
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Mojo::Promise]',
    is => 'ro',
    required => 1,
);

has 'resolve_filter' => ( # truthy return means *DO* filter out
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    is => 'ro',
    required => 1,
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub { return sub {}; },
);

has 'reject_filter' => ( # truthy return means *DO* filter out
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    is => 'ro',
    required => 1,
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub { return sub {}; },
);

has '_promises_state_tracker' => (
    # numbered hashref whose primary keys correspond to passed promise-array's indices
    # secondary keys are flags for whether each original promise filtered
    # and whether promise resolved/rejected,
    # plus the original promise itself, e.g. : 
    # { 0 => { filtered => (undef|1), ror => (undef|1), original_promise => (Mojo::Promise) } }
    isa => 'HashRef[HashRef]',
    is => 'ro',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_promises_state_tracker',
);


sub _build_promises_state_tracker {
    my $self = shift;
    my $i = 0;
    return { map { $i++ => { original_promise => $_ } } @{$self->promises} };
}

sub _resolve_or_reject_self_if_last_child {
    my $self = shift;

    my @ror = grep { $_->{ror} } values %{$self->_promises_state_tracker};
        # gather the thus-far resolved-or-rejected promises
    return unless scalar keys %{$self->_promises_state_tracker} == scalar @ror;
        # return unless we have as many ror promises as were passed in

    my @unfiltered = map { $_->{original_promise} } grep { !$_->{filtered} } values %{$self->_promises_state_tracker};
    return Mojo::Promise->all(@unfiltered)->then(sub {
        $self->resolve(@_)
    })->catch(sub {
        $self->reject(@_)
    });
}

sub filter {
    my $self = shift;

    for my $i (0 .. $#{$self->promises}) {
        $self->promises->[$i]->then(sub {
            $self->_promises_state_tracker->{$i}->{filtered} = 1
                if $self->resolve_filter->(@_);
        })->catch(sub {
            $self->_promises_state_tracker->{$i}->{filtered} = 1
                if $self->reject_filter->(@_);
        })->finally(sub {
            $self->_promises_state_tracker->{$i}->{ror} = 1;
                # ror = Resolved Or Rejected
            $self->_resolve_or_reject_self_if_last_child();
        });
    }

    return $self;
}

no Moose;

1;
```

Use as :

```
my $re_filter = qr/some special text/;
my $reject_filter = sub {
        my $v = shift;
        return 1 if ref \$v eq 'SCALAR' && $v =~ $re_filter;
    };

my $p = Mojo::Promise::Filter->new(
        reject_filter => $reject_filter,
        promises => \@promises
    );

return $p->filter;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what this does, but here goes.

- Mojolicious doesn't use Moose. I would think long and hard whether I'd extend a [Mojo::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Base) class with Moose. Does this work properly?
- There are several instances of `required` together with `default` and `lazy` in your new attributes. Those do not make sense together. If it's `required` it needs to be passed in at construction. There is no need to make it `lazy` then as it will always be there from the start.
- Your `default` for both `reject_filter` as well as `resolve_filter` are subs that return `undef` implicitly. That means if you don't pass those in, everything is discarded. Is that the intended behavior?
- <strike>Your class is a subclass of `Mojo::Promise`, so there is no need to call `Mojo::Promise->all`. It's got an inherited `->all` method that you can call on `$self`.</strike> (`Mojo::Promise->all`) returns a new object, so this breaks.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm already using Moose elsewhere in my Mojo app, so I figured it wouldn't incur a significant overhead to use here. I trust that Moose handles extending a non-Moose class well enough, though I'll admit I don't know the subtle ways in which things might act quirky. I will look into "MooseX::NonMoose", or maybe not using Moose at all. Good catch with required+lazy. Yes, a default of "sub {}" returning undef means default behviour is for no promises to be filtered out. I think you might be right about being able to call just "$self->all(@unfiltered)", I will test it out. Thanks again !

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the overhead regarding Moose, just that Mojolicious goes out of its way to not have Moose while maintaining a similar interface. I don't know what kind of things might happen there. Just wanted to note that down.

Comment: I tried switching Mojo::Promise->all to $self->all, but it broke. Maybe related to the fact that method "all" "[r]eturns a new Mojo::Promise object [...]", per docs ? Or maybe because in the source for Mojo::Promise->all, it calls $class->new;, but $class is now Mojo::Promise::Filter and I told Moose to require attribute "promises", so "all" method fails internally to construct a new object ? Hm. Does Mojolicious offer a similar type system to Moose's ? I like being able to have Moose enforce, say, "isa => 'HashRef[HashRef]'". Compatibility vouch : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30809096

Comment: @robut as far as I know it doesn't have any types. It's trying to be simple and on the point. My advice on the `all` was a guess based on the class hierarchy. Sorry that that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Mojolicious has roles already.

```
 package Mojo::Promise::Role::Filter {
     use Mojo::Base '-role';
     ...; # stuff you want in the Promise class
     }

 my $promise->with_roles( '+Filter' )->new;
 ...;
```

See, for instance, [Mojo::Promise::Role::Any](https://github.com/briandfoy/mojo_promise_role_any).